# simple to use/embed binary-safe key/value DB

Tags: database, sqlite, nosql, redis

I am searching for a DB which:

- can safe binary-key/binary-value pairs and return them by key,
- is easy to use,
- is easy to embed in my C++ application,
- does not have problems with huge amount of data (~100GB) on low-end machines (i.e. any desktop machine which just have enough hard disk space),
- does not have problems with huge amount of key/value pairs (1000M or more),
- stores the data on hard disk,
- does initialize very fast / instantly on a restart given previous data.

More specifically, I want to use it here: [png-db](https://github.com/albertz/png-db).

So far, I have tried:

- The filesystem itself, keys stored in hex representation as filenames, values as file content.

  The only real problem was the huge amount of key/value pairs. About 50MB of data resulted in about 100k files (i.e. key/value pairs).
- [Redis](http://redis.io/).

  The main problem is that it tries to keep everything in memory (or its own virtual memory implementation but that doesn't really solve the problem). So obviously it cannot handle such huge amounts of data. And startup is also very slow because it reads the whole DB into memory.
- [KyotoCabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/).

  Works best so far but has some strange behavior on shutting down and reloading the DB. Esp. for reloading, it sometimes takes several minutes to load the DB (about 1GB in size). I don't see why loading the DB shouldn't take constant time.

Other DBs I thought about:

- SQLite. I haven't really worked with it yet; I only know that it is esp. made to be embedded. But I have the feeling that the SQL language is a bit overkill for my use-case and that I also might get trouble with binary data (or I am not sure how I should handle that; escape everything? that would be quite slow).

So, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

[Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/gYaDfo) has the capabilities that you're looking for. It's library that links into your application. It's small and very fast. It supports key/value pairs and an easy-to-use API. It's very [portable, reliable and scalable](http://bit.ly/eKvOPB). It runs on lots of platforms. It's designed to be used in constrained environments and runs on lots of different devices and appliances.

Disclaimer: I'm the Product Manager for Berkeley DB, so I'm a little biased. But BDB was designed to do exactly what you're looking for -- fast, reliable, portable, scalable embedded data storage. We've been doing key/value pairs for years. We were NoSQL before NoSQL was popular. :-)

Good luck in your search. - Dave

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendation. I already considered it but didn't found a quick&simple HOWTO and wasn't sure if it really fits my needs so I went with the other mentioned DBs. Can you give me a good reference where I can find what I need? Something like the example [here](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/api/).

Comment: There are several code examples included with the Berkeley DB download. There are also two recorded BDB tutorials on the "Learn More" tab for BDB here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/learnmore/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with converting the binary keys to a hex implementation, you can try out any database you like, but on low-end machines, the main bottleneck will be the disk IO.

Will you have many tables and relationships between them, or will it just be a large bucket of key/value pairs? If it is such a simple list, you can write something yourself. A base for this could be the Structured Storage implementation of Windows. This is actually kind of a filesystem within a file and is used by Microsoft Office applications including Word and Access to store their data in.

Writing to these files can be very fast, but they get fragmented over time, because data is written at the end if there isn't a large enough free spot. In that case you will need to compact the file, which obviously takes a little time. Therefor, it would be best not to create huge files, but combine the powers of the file system with the power of these files, because it will keep you from cereating millions of files (wasting millions of partial clusters) while it can still be maintained easily because the data files aren't to big either.

Of course you could come up with your own datafile too, if structured storage appears to be too complex or slow or does have too much overhead.

But remember, it will be tough to get a 100 GB database to run fast *and* instantly from a simple single disk desktop setup.

Comment: It will just be a large bucket of key/value pairs. But I need a cross-platform solution. I already thought about implementing it myself but I don't really want to reinvent the wheel; I'm quite sure there must be something already out there which fits perfectly here.

Comment: Ah, what I mean with fast: Given a similar sized real filesystem on such a machine, the random file access performance should be about the same or slower than a random key/value access in the DB. And startup of the DB system should be about the same as mounting such a filesystem. (After all, maybe something like ReiserFS is really the best fit for me but I am not sure.)

Comment: If you want it to be faster than the file system, you cannot use the file system. :)